# Refreshing @Resource and @Autowired bean at Runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have one bean which is define in the SpringConfiguration and which gets initialised at the startup.
This bean(Map) is populated by querying the database at startup.

Now the database gets update frequently and I have implemented the ApplicationListener and was trying to implement a cache using TimerTask.

The code of timertask runs fine and in that i am accessing the bean using ApplicationContext but not able to refresh/reinitialize the bean with the new database results.

The @Resource and @Autowired beans still shows the old value.

I want to refresh/Reinitialize the @Autowired / @Resource bean at Runtime. Please advise

Comment: you can make another API that can run the same function which runs at the startup.  And then you can schedule this API by a cron job to run at frequent intervals

Comment: some codes to show the problem will be helpful for me to understand the more problem more clearly such as the how you update that bean in applicationListener etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an ORM it should handle it for you.

Otherwise, if you are doing it on you own, you can annotate the bean with `@RefreshScope` and when you detect a change *(wherever method you are using like cron or listener)* then just refresh the context from the actuator like:

http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh

Cheers!

pd: Actuator should be enabled and accesible.